# how to increase threads distribution in java/scala?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I'm replicate to duplicate an `exception` in non thread safe code so that it would in infinite loop at `findEntry0` `while loop` so I created this code:

```
val map = mutable.Map[Int, String]()
val rand = new Random()
def nextInt() = rand.nextInt(1000000)

for (i <- 1 to 1000) {
  new Thread(new Runnable {
    def run(): Unit = {
      while (true) {
        val key = nextInt()
        map.put(key, "some string")
        map.contains(key)
        println(s"thread ${System.currentTimeMillis()} ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      }
    }
  }).start()
}
Thread.sleep(120000)
```

it prints:

```
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080460 Thread-251
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
thread 1455123080657 Thread-219
```

as you can see it looks like the threads are running `sequentially` and not in parallel by the timestamps, am i doing something wrong? how can I get them to run actually concurrently?

am i doing something wrong? i want the threads to run concurrently.

Comment: How much time a thread will get a CPU slice for is OS dependent. In that slice Thread 251 executed the while loop X number of times. Then Thread 219 executed Y number of times and so on... then depending on the scheduler 251 may come back and again execute.. If the threads were not running concurrently only one thread would have kept executing and theoretically even that is possible here assuming your machine has just one processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample is not very reliable. Actually it's happening what you expect.
Threads are executed in parallel on your machine. But actually you have limited amount of processors/cores so current context is switching between `1000` threads you've created each and every X ms. Obviously before context switch from one thread to another couple of lines where able to be written.

What I would suggest you - is to mimimize amount of parallel threads to some countable amounts  and also add `10ms` sleep inside your infinite loop.
 This allow you to see diversity of how all threads works concurrently.

```
thread 1455123868703 Thread-3
thread 1455123868703 Thread-6
thread 1455123868703 Thread-9
thread 1455123868703 Thread-8
thread 1455123868703 Thread-2
thread 1455123868703 Thread-7
thread 1455123868721 Thread-9
thread 1455123868721 Thread-2
thread 1455123868721 Thread-4
thread 1455123868721 Thread-5
thread 1455123868721 Thread-6
thread 1455123868721 Thread-8
thread 1455123868721 Thread-3
thread 1455123868721 Thread-7
thread 1455123868721 Thread-0
thread 1455123868721 Thread-1
```